# How to create mask in a machine independent way?

Tags: dependencies, bitwise-operators, bit, bitmask, independent-set

So I'm practicing some programming interview questions, and stumbled across this [sample pdf](http://elementsofprogramminginterviews.com/sample/epilight_cpp_new.pdf) which recommends "Understand how to use masks and create them in an machine independent way". But it doesn't eloborate the difference between machine dependent and machine independent mask.

I usually just figure out the integer that provides the mask that I want, for example if I only want the last 4 bits I would do:

```
int y = x & 15;
```

I don't understand why this would be machine dependent, if it is.

So what is an example of creating a mask that is machine independent? And what is an example of creating a mask that is machine dependent?

Perhaps what they are talking about is what if you need a mask for something that isn't an integer, in which case my approach wouldn't work (I've never needed a mask for anything except for integers)?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that "machine independent" here means that your code should perform the desired operation (e.g. a mask and shift) regardless of the compiler and/or machine on which it runs. For example, different compilers and systems treat the length of data types differently. If you write a bitshift on ints that presumes a size of 4 bytes, this would not be "machine independent". Some compilers treat ints as 8 bytes.